# How to stop\close\kill tcp connection on macOS

Tags: macos, tcp, terminal

First of all this is not a duplicate. Overall my question is:
I have another application currently running on macOS and I want to **cut** (sever or close or stop) it **tcp connection** from terminal. The problem is I don't want to **kill process** 'cause this is a solution what I found in another answers. + I have an access to sudo and I know the PID.

What I did and it doesn't work:

```
lsof -i TCP:X | awk '/LISTEN/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

I tried to change X to particular value which I got from this command

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP
```

The second thing placed here https://www.scm.keele.ac.uk/staff/stan/2016/05/16/closing-sockets-without-killing-processes/

But from that line `lldb -p $PID` I got an error like this:

`error: attach failed: attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries when the attached failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.)`

Maybe I missed something or maybe I should find a special program for my purpose? The Windows I see have one -> https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html

I'm really curious about it 'cause all answers which I found suggests users to **kill** all process. But I don't want it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok.. just try to learn code from here -> https://github.com/doug-leith/appFirewall

Thanks dude for providing minus feedback for me. But my answer is the only one on internet which lead to working firewall!